# Correct Evaluation of Random Forest on fixed training/test set

Tags: random-forest, model-comparison, information-retrieval

I have to test the performance of Random Forest on the same dataset (text classification) with about 118.000 instances of which about 1/3 is used for training and 2/3 is used for testing. The division is given, so I cannot modify either the test or the training set.

I need to conduct an investigation about which parameters and/or features are best for the classification problem given a certain metric. Now, for the randomness of random forest each run I obtain a different output predictor, that will generate different results, and so the metric will vary from run to run. 
So my initial idea was to simply run the random forest a certain number n of times (say n=4) and take the average value of the given metric as representative of that particular configuration, in order to compare with the other possibilities.

Probably a better approach would make use of a statistical test in order to establish to which degree we can assure that one model is better than another. How do you suggest to perform this considering the particular case I've mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a randomization test, which is kind of like a statistical test except you don  really have to check the parameters of the distributions. Here's how it could work to compare two two classifiers A and B:

- get the accuracies (or whatever metric) for maybe 10 or 20 runs for each classifier, so you have a set of scores $a_i$ and a set of scores $b_i$.
- compare average of $a_i$ and average of $b_i$, say $avg(a_i)>avg(b_i)$, and $avg(a_i) - avg(b_i) = d$
- null hypothesis: A and B are actually the same, we just got better scores $a_i$ by chance.
- The question is: how likely is it that we observe a difference of $d$ between means?
- This is where you can do randomization or else a statistical test:
  put all your $a_i$ and $b_i$ scores in a set, and repeatedly divide them randomly in two. How often do you observe a difference of $d$ or more? That's an estimate of the probability that A and B are indeed equivalent.
- I say 10 or 20 runs for each classifier, if time permits because with more data you will have more reliable probability estimates... but if you have many candidate feature sets that's a lot of comparisons to be made.

Note that if you have to choose a feature /parameter set that will maximize your expected accuracy (or whatever metric), then eventually you should probably choose the one with the highest average accuracy. The only thing you get here is a measure of confidence for the optimality of your choice.

Finally I would add a word of warning about this kind of optimization: by optimizing (i.e. picking the best feature set) on the test data you are actually making that test data become training data (for the optimization). That's ok if you're just trying to get the best classifier possible given the available data, but you have to be aware that its accuracy (...) was tested on training data, and on new data it probably won't perform as well.

Answer (score 0):

Average may not be the best statistic in this case. Use box whisker plots as shown below. Take at least 10 runs for each feature set (FS). Say you have 6 feature sets (FS1 to FS6) and the metric on the $y$ axis should be low for good performance of the model. In this example, FS1 has low median but is not very consistent over the 10 runs. On the other hand FS5 has low relatively low value for the metric and is also fairly consistent. Note that even though FS6 is highly consistent, it has a higher value for the metric and therefore should not usually be preferred. Thus, the user can choose the best feature set by trading-off between the accuracy of the model and its consistency.

[image]